# Size of file, human readable

Tags: python

How would I get the human readable output of `__sizeof__`. For example:

```
# No
>>> x.__sizeof__()
16725808

# Yes
>>> x.__sizeof__()
16.7 MB
```

Comment: Why are you using `x.__sizeof__()` directly and not [`sys.getsizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)?

Comment: In any case, `object.__sizeof__()` **must** return a size as an integer, not a formatted string.

Comment: http://pint.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/